# How to get a friendly attribute name in API payload response?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want the get request to return a friendly names instead of the actual db column names. Is it possible?

my model class

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; } 

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Phone { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

payload that is generated. Note that the First Name is not changed

```
{
  "employeeID": 1501,
  "firstName": "Syed Omar",
  "lastName": "Khan",
  "phone": "9234567891",
  "email": "Syed Omar@yahoo.com",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change json property name of serialized class you can use corresponding attribute depending on json library used. For `System.Text.Json` it would be  [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1). For Newtonsoft's Json.NET - `JsonPropertyAttribute`:

```cs
[JsonPropertyName("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Or

```cs
[JsonProperty("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one problem here, while sending payload back to sever for post or put, it expects the names to be converted to the JSON property name. In this case I have modify my client application and have all the field names to match this. Is there any easy way to handle this?

Comment: @SamK no, there is no out of the box solution for this. You can use different models for return and post. But I would say that your front end should handle this  `FirstName -> First Name` conversion and not the API.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by decorating the property name like below

```
[JsonPropertyName("Employee ID")]
public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("First Name")] 
public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```